# Manipulate path string BATCH

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I need to process a full path to a file, i.e. C:\fold1\fold2...\foldN\filename.dat in order to get the parent file folder and file name separately, that is root=C:\fold1\fold2...\foldN and file=filaname.dat.

This because I want to generalise a call to a program no matter from where you call the main .bat (this one), such to be able to perform a `pushd` to %root% before calling this specific program.

I am working at this, but I get stack when posing `line=%%c`:

```
: before remove quotes from %var%
set var=%var:"=%

if exist %temp% (
    if exist %temp%\filepath.txt del %temp%\filepath.txt
    echo %var% > %temp%\filepath.txt
)
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%z in (%temp%\filepath.txt) do (
    set line=%%z
    echo Line writes %line%.
    set root=empty
    goto :processtoken
)

:processtoken
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%b in ("%line%") do (
    echo %%b
    echo %%c
    set  line=%%c rem this does not work, why??
    echo Now line writes %line%

    if "%root%"=="empty" (
        echo [INFO] Root is empty, initialising..
        echo %%c
        set root=%%c
    ) else (
        set root=%root%\%%c
    )
    echo Root is %root%
    goto :end
)
```

The problem I am facing is that when I print to see how %line% has changed, it shows that %line% (after `set line=%%c` corresponds to the FULL PATH (while my intention is to recursively get to the file name, I still need to add the condition in finding the `"\"` string in %%c, when not present anymore it will mean we got to the final step, i.e. %root% will now correspond to the final root folder).

Thanks to who will try to help me resolving this issue.

EDIT:
this main program is called as follow:

prog arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5

arg5 is the path to the file which will internally be the argument for this other program. To be as general as possible I want to made functional this program no matter from where you call it. Still you have two options:

- you are already in the folder containing the file to be processed by this internally called program, in such case arg5 will be passed as filename.dat (without quotes, except if it contains spaces)
- you are not in the root folder so you pass directly the FULL PATH (in double quotes if it contains spaces).

The problem is in case 2, since this internal program works properly when you call it from root directory and you pass to it only FILENAME.DAT.

This is why I posed this question. %var% is simply arg5, in the ways I explained hereby.

I hope I have been a little more clear than before.

PS. I'm not an experienced programmer in all ways, so I do apologise if I miss in clearance and professionalism. The write/read from/to %temp% folder was just to exploit a newer way of programming in batch, nothing else. I knew it was superfluous.

Comment: Btw. You're missing an `exit /b` after your main code and your `:processtoken` function

Comment: Whilst you may receive some answers based upon what you've posted, I'd be reluctant to advise a methodology without undertanding exactly what `%var%` is. I think you should really tell us how and where it is defined, what it could contain, (character content and size), and how, and what exactly, you're using to 'call the main .bat' and any arguments to it). There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65407613/edit) button, you can use to update your question to include such information.

Comment: `set line=%%c` works, it is `echo Now line writes %line%` that is failing due to lack of [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (alternatively, you could try `call echo Now line writes %%line%%`, or simply `set line`). Anyway, resolving paths with string manipulation should generally be avoided, because it is prone to errors…

Comment: @jeb the code is just an extract, of course I have exit /b in :end section :)

Comment: @Compo thanks for your reply. %var% is the string of the path that I pass as 5th argument in the main program. That is 
`set var=%5
if "%var%"=="" (
 echo [ERROR] 6th input. Please specify an input .dat file!
 goto :error
)`

where %5 is passed as "C:\fold1\fold2\...\foldN\filename-dat" in cmd line

Comment: @aschipfl tried your solution and worked !! Thanks. What would you suggest then??

Comment: We need to be certain of exactly how that command line is being entered when passed via the cmd line. It is very important that we know because the variable is being defined only after it is received through a process which could itself alter that string. If it is always doublequoted, will always contain a fully qualified absolute path, and cannot contain problematic characters, you should have the information you need already. e.g. `%~nx5` will be the filename and extension, and `%~dp5` will be the drive letter and path, (with a trailing back slash). `Set "file=%~nx5"`, and `Set "root=%~dp5"`

Comment: Well, there is already an answer, which avoids string manipulation – does it not help you? And you should follow Compo's advice of [edit]ing your question (rather than providing additional information spread over multiple comments)…

Comment: IF the variable `var` is nothing more than a file path, there is no reason to write it to a file and then read it back with a `FOR` command.  And if you are removing the surrounding quotes with the `SET` command there is no reason for that as well because the `FOR` command and command line arguments can do that as well.  Your question as presented does not meet the [mcve] requirements because you have not specified how the variable `VAR` is getting assigned.

Comment: @Squashman I made the edit, hope this solves some previous misunderstandings. If not, please do tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the for-variable modifiers (`FOR /?`)

`root=%%~dpz` is used to expand to: d=drive and p=path of z
`file=%%~nxz` is used to expand to: n=name and x=extension of z

Then you can change your block to

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%z in (%temp%\filepath.txt) do (
    set "line=%%z"
    set "root=%%~dpz"
    set "file=%%~nxz"
    REM ** Show the variables
    set root
    set file
)
```

Comment: any benefi5 for `1,*` vs `1*` that I should be aware of, or just a matter of personal preference?  (I only ask because I prefer the lazy character omission, and while its never been of issue for me personally, its the sort of thing I could see having some hidden gotcha)

Comment: @BenPersonick I don't think so, they are just two ways of expressing the same thing

Comment: @jeb so as you say, if %%z reads directly the entire file path (root\filename) setting root=%%~dpz and file=%%~nxz automatically saves the problem ??

Comment: @micesp yeah, thats been my assumption for 20 years, but Jeb has been doing cmd scripting at least double that, and there are always quirks and undocumented features/behaviors, that everyone is brings to each others attn.

Comment: @BenPersonick with last comment do you refer to difference between `1*` and `1,*` or the other one? I am confused since you mention Jeb in your comment..

Comment: @MicEsp, just because you didn't respond to my comment under your main question, I thought, I'd mention it here. The reason being that it uses the same methods as used in the answer above, but does not require that you need a [tag:for-loop] or anything like that, just two short lines of code, `Set "file=%~nx5"`, and `Set "root=%~dp5"`, are all that are required to do what you need.

Comment: @BenPersonick Thanks, but in this case I simply copy the original code snippet without any deeper thoughts :-)

Comment: Thanks, I figured that was the most likely, but thought I'd check and see if there was anything more to it :) Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2):

since you mentioned `set var=%5` in a comment:

```
set "root=%~dp5"
set "file=%~nx5"
```

should be all you need. See `call /?` for more details.

Comment: I've offered exactly that code in two separate comments now over the last few hours, with no response @Stephan. It is possible that the OP has accepted an answer, and thererfore does not intend to read anything more!

Comment: @Compo: you may be right, but that shouldn't keep us from giving answers for future searchers. OP is supposed to accept the answer that helped them (most). Over time, votes will show the perceived value of the answer(s).

Comment: BTW Stephan, you may also note that I asked about what that argument may contain for a reason too. If the fifth argument can contain a file path without a drive, or a filename without a drive or path, then `%~dp5` would probably be propagated with the current drive and directory instead. That and the fact that even @aschipfl reminded the OP to update their question with the required information is why I left my responses as comments as opposed to an official answer. _There is insufficient information for us to offer the most suitable code or methodology for the task._

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this in a batch-file would be to use the PowerShell `Split-Path` command designed to do this.

```
SET "THEFILE=%TEMP%\file path.txt"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command
    """$([Convert]::ToChar(34))$(Split-Path -Path """%THEFILE%""")$([Convert]::ToChar(34)) $([Convert]::ToChar(34))$(Split-Path -Path """%THEFILE%""" -Leaf)$([Convert]::ToChar(34))"""') DO (
    SET "FILESTRING=%%A"
)

SET "PATHPART="
FOR %%A IN (%FILESTRING%) DO (
    IF NOT DEFINED PATHPART (SET "PATHPART=%%~A") ELSE (SET "FILEPART=%%~A")
)
ECHO PATHPART is "%PATHPART%"
ECHO FILEPART is "%FILEPART%"
```

Of course, it is easier if the script is written for PowerShell.

```
$TheFile = "$Env:TEMP\filepath.txt"
$PathPart = Split-Path -Path $TheFile
$FilePart = Split-Path -Path $TheFile -Leaf
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually, it appears that splitting the path is not needed to use PUSHD. Just add `\..` to the end.

```
PUSHD C:\Users\joe\afile.txt\..
```

Comment: Just to let you know that you're not supposed to be splitting up the filename itself, you're supposed to be splitting up the name of the file written to its content!